# How do I make the .Net HttpWebRequest IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatible in Unity?

Tags: c#-2.0, ipv6, unity-game-engine

Apple has mandated that all apps must support IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility, and I'm in the process of upgrading our apps to do so.  For the most part we're using the high level Unity APIs, so this is not a problem.

However, in one app we needed to use the lower level System.Net.HttpWebRequest interface in order to support a slightly more complex "PUT" operation, with some returned data.

This is proving to be problematic.  We're getting a NameResolutionFailure exception in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetWriteStreamError when we attempt HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream().  We do not see this exception on a normal IPv4 network.

This indicates to me that the DNS is failing, and thus something is wrong with how we're using HttpWebRequest.  Is HttpWebRequest not compliant with IPv6 in the .Net version Unity is using (.NET 2.0)?  I've searched through the documentation without success.

At this point my next step is to either begin writing socket level code to support IPv6 in this app, or write a custom plugin for iOS.  Neither of these are avenues I'd like to pursue, so I'm hoping someone else can suggest a better plan.

Comment: Have you [updated Unity](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/05/10/unity-and-ipv6-support/)?

Comment: Yes, I should have updated this some time ago, updating Unity resolved the issue.